# Captioning Phone- Ethernet Splitter or Switch

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I have a captioning phone that I use for work (hard of hearing) and the phone requires an internet connection. Seeing that the wifi is building wide it is recommended that we use an ethernet connection with this phone.

My question is whether or not I should use a splitter or a switch for the phone seeing that my ethernet port is used by the office computer. Keep in mind that the phone line is analog so I will still be able to receive incoming calls if I used a switch and it was turned to off. (just not captions).

Wifi is for guests not the office computers/desktops

Comment: Use a switch...

Comment: Could You recommend a switch for switching between the two? Also do you just push a button to switch between the two options or? Sorry I am new to all this.

Comment: `1.` Any SOHO switch will do. Google it. `2.` You don't "switch" a switch. You plug the switch into the network jack in the wall and then plug your network devices into the switch. That's it. Just make sure not to connect two switch ports together.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of ethernet, a switch doesn't mean something that you can flip on and off like a light switch. Rather, it's a box with multiple cables connected to it, which *internally* switches data from one path to another, the way a switchboard operator would have done a century ago.

An ethernet switch (or hub, but those are hard to find now) is perfect for your purposes, as it will allow you to connect two downstream devices (computer and phone) to a single upstream connection. Both will be able to use the network connection all the time, as if they had their own direct connection. Because switches almost always have at least 4 ports, you'd also be able to connect a laptop or another wired ethernet device if necessary.

Here's a very cheap switch from a reputable brand (Netgear) and vendor:
 http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122607

You will also need a total of three ethernet cables, one for the computer, one for the phone, and one to connect the switch to the wall jack.

Comment: Good answer, but he might also want to get a **layer 3** switch (aka a router) which can do NAT, and also MAC spoofing, in case the downstream router/switch does MAC whitelisting. If it does 802.1x he might have a hard time getting it connected without the official support of his company's IT staff (which, it is probably a good idea to get their buy-in in the first place). Rather than have him buy something, in this situation I'd recommend that he ask his IT folks what *they* think he should do. Maybe they could even provide him with a spare switch for free.

Comment: You probably mean the *upstream* router/switch. There are certainly potential complexities that would be best handled with support from the IT staff. It would be sad to have a cheap switch in hand only to find that a) it won't work, b) IT would supply one free, and/or c) IT now thinks you're one of those users who don't trust them.

Comment: Thanks everyone we actually don't have an IT guy on hand at the moment. I think they are looking for a new one. I will try the switch and keep let you know.